# Cannot convert type 'Xamarin.Essentials.ShareFile[]' to <Xamarin.Essentials.ShareFile>

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

**error: Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'Xamarin.Essentials.ShareFile[]' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Xamarin.Essentials.ShareFile>'**

code should work bc i got it from microsoft docs: **ref:** [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/share?tabs=ios)

```
 await Share.RequestAsync(new ShareMultipleFilesRequest
 {
     Files = new ShareFile[] { new ShareFile(filepath1), new ShareFile(filepath2) }
 });
```

Comment: [Api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.essentials.sharemultiplefilesrequest?view=xamarin-essentials) updated but sample code in your link not updated yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `ShareMultipleFilesRequest.Files` is a list you need to provide a list:

```
await Share.RequestAsync(new ShareMultipleFilesRequest
{
    Files = new List<ShareFile> { new ShareFile(filepath1), new ShareFile(filepath2) }
});
```

Comment: got it, yeah i couldnt find anything on google so thanks for your help